# Where clause after String.Join in Linq to Entites

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Linq to Entites query where I have implemented the logic. But, I have done the query `where` clause performs after string join. BTW, I need to know how can I join the string first before doing the `where` filter. When I execute the query `where` clause after the string join, it takes so long to filter the records. Since my database have nearly 2 lakh sample records.

**Here is my query what I am looking for:**

```
// But the below query throws string join cannot be converted to store expression.

var NewBibContentsModel = (from x in db.BibContents
                                       where (x.TagNo == "245" && string.Join(" ", x.NormValue) == aa.CurrentTitle) || ((x.TagNo == "020") || (x.TagNo == "022") && string.Join(" ", x.NormValue) == aa.CurrentISBN)
                                       select new
             {
                 BibId = x.BibId,
                 Title = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == "245" orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue),
                 Author = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && splitted.Contains(a.TagNo) && a.NormValue != null select a.TagNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                 ISBN = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.NormValue != null && (a.TagNo == "020" || a.TagNo == "022") orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue)
             }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new BibContentsModel
            {
                BibId = x.BibId,
                Title = string.Join(" ", x.Title),
                Author = string.Join(" ", (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == x.Author orderby a.Id select a.NormValue)),
                ISBN = string.Join(" ", x.ISBN),
                RRId = aa.RRId
            }).ToList();
```

**Query with Where clause after string Join**

// The below query takes so much of time to filter the records.

```
var NewBibContentsModel = (from x in db.BibContents

                                       select new
             {
                 BibId = x.BibId,
                 Title = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == "245" orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue),
                 //Tit = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == line.BibId && a.TagNo == "245" && a.Sfld == "a" select a.NormValue).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Author = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && splitted.Contains(a.TagNo) && a.NormValue != null select a.TagNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                 ISBN = (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.NormValue != null && (a.TagNo == "020" || a.TagNo == "022") orderby a.Id ascending select a.NormValue)
             }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new BibContentsModel
            {
                BibId = x.BibId,
                Title = string.Join(" ", x.Title),
                Author = string.Join(" ", (from a in db.BibContents where a.BibId == x.BibId && a.TagNo == x.Author orderby a.Id select a.NormValue)),
                ISBN = string.Join(" ", x.ISBN),
                RRId = aa.RRId
            }).Where (x=> x.Title == aa.CurrentTitle || (x.ISBN == aa.CurrentISBN)).ToList();
```

Any help or suggestion to this problem will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems that you have pretty bad db design. You should use stored procedures on tasks like this. Maybe posting a db diagram and desired result will help us to come up with something better.